# How to find the length of line segments using python

Tags: python, line

I want to calculate the length of (any number of) line segments using Python. I used the following code, but I encounter that tuples can not have subtraction as operands. How can I overcome that? I would like to know if I missed any important Python concept.

```
from itertools import starmap
import math
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
    def move(self,dx,dy):
        self.x+=dx
        self.y+=dy


class LineString(object):

    def __init__(self,*args): # A method with any number of arguments, args

        self.args=[Point(*args) for p in args] # A list of Points

    def length(self):
        pairs=zip(self.args, self.args[1:])
        return sum(starmap(distance,pairs))

def distance(p1, p2):
    a = p1.x,p1.y
    b = p2.x,p2.y

    print (math.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2-(a[1]-b[1])**2))
    # calculates distance between two given points p1 and p2
    return math.sqrt((a** 2)+ (b** 2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Tests for LineString
    # ===================================
    lin1 = LineString((1, 1), (0, 2))

    assert lin1.length() == sqrt(2.0)

    lin1.move(-1, -1) # Move by -1 and -1 for x and y respectively

    assert lin1[0].y == 0 # Inspect the y value of the start point.
    # Implement this by overloading __getitem__(self, key) in your class.

    lin2 = LineString((1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2))

    assert lin2.length() == 2.0

    lin2.move(-1, -1) # Move by -1 and -1 for x and y respectively

    assert lin2.length() == 2.0

    assert lin2[-1].x == 1 # Inspect the x value of the end point.

    print ('Success! Line tests passed!')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already mentioned, it has to be `Point(*p)` intead of `Point(*args)`. The latter would pass *all* the point-tuples to the constructor of each point. You also have to fix `distance`, though.

```
def __init__(self, *args):
    self.args=[Point(*p) for p in args]

def distance(p1, p2):
    return math.sqrt((p1.x-p2.x)**2 + (p1.y-p2.y)**2)
```

However, instead of creating your own `Point` class, an "important Python concept" that you can use instead are built-in [`complex`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#complex) [numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number), making `distance` much simpler:

```
def __init__(self, *args):
    self.args=[complex(*p) for p in args]

def distance(p1, p2):
    return abs(p1 - p2)
```

Answer (score 4):

math module have hypot function for this purpose

> math.hypot(x, y)
>
> Return the Euclidean norm, sqrt(x*x + y*y). This is the length of the vector from the origin to point (x, y).

Here is my suggestion

```
return math.hypot(p1.x - p2.x, p1.y - p2.y)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't support exponentiation (and other math operations) for tuples. While it's possible to have code like this:

```
print (1, 2) * 3       # produces (1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
print (1, 2) + (1, 2)  # produces (1, 2, 1, 2)
```

it's not a vector computations on the entire tuple. It's just a syntactic sugar for tuples concatenation.

Also it seems that the snippet has a few typos/bugs.

The line `self.args=[Point(*args) for p in args]` should be rather `self.args=[Point(*p) for p in args]`

Class `LineString` doesn't have `move()` method.

And the `distance()` calculation should be slightly changed (notice that I replaced `-` with `+` in the formula):

```
return math.sqrt((p1.x - p2.x)**2 + (p1.y - p2.y)**2)
```